# ASP.NET MVC and trace output bugs out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I haven't been able to find much about this but am I the only one that noticed if you enabled tracing output in an ASP.NET MVC project it outputs the whole trace output once per every MVC user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to use http:// ... /trace.axd instead.